# Get status of SMS send though Twilio notify

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I have send notification messages using Twilio api. Messages are sending properly.

```
$notification = $client
    ->notify->services($serviceSid)
    ->notifications->create([
        "toBinding" => [
            '{"binding_type":"sms", "address":"+971444444444"}',
            '{"binding_type":"sms", "address":"+971444444445"}'
        ],
        'body' => 'Test message 8'
    ]);
```

Response of the request is 201 and returning a sid starting with `'NT'`. How to track status of this messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

twilio has a `callback` status webhook ,  you need to configure it inorder to track the delivery status of an sms message

```
$notification = $client
    ->notify->services($serviceSid)
    ->notifications->create([
        "toBinding" => [
            '{"binding_type":"sms", "address":"+971444444444"}',
            '{"binding_type":"sms", "address":"+971444444445"}'
        ],
        'body' => 'Test message 8'
        'statusCallback' => "your public end point to track sms delivery status"
    ]);
```

see more [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-confirm-delivery-in-php#receive-status-events-in-your-web-application)

Comment: Doesn't seems to work for me. Looks like It is working only for 
`$twilio->messages->create`

Answer (score 5):

Should be like this:

PHP:

```
$notification = $client
    ->notify->services($serviceSid)
    ->notifications->create([
        "toBinding" => [
            '{"binding_type":"sms", "address":"+971444444444"}',
            '{"binding_type":"sms", "address":"+971444444445"}'
        ],
        'body' => 'Test message 8'
        'sms' => ['status_callback' => 'https://youcallbackurl.com']
    ]);
```

Or Javascript

```
const service = twilio.notify.services(notifyId);
const bindings = numbers.map(number => {
        return JSON.stringify({ 
            binding_type: 'sms', 
            address: number,
        });
    });

service.notifications.create({
        toBinding: bindings,
        body: message,
                sms: {
                    status_callback: 'https://youcallbackurl.com'
                }
  })
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer was sitting at -1 votes because this seems to be the correct way to configure your callback URL with the Notify API (in PHP anyway) while the chosen answer does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Step to send Multiple SMS via Twilio using PHP

1. Create Account on Twilio
2. Get a Twilio Number
3. Add Phone numbers here: https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/verified
4. Create a notification Service here: https://www.twilio.com/console/notify/services and copy "SERVICE SID" (This will be used in code)
5. Create a Message Service here: https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/services
6. Select `MESSAGING SERVICE SID` under Notify - Configuration's page, what you have created on 5th step:

```
$sid = 'ACb2f967a907520b85b4eba3e8151d0040'; //twilio service SID
$token = '03e066de1020f3a87cec37bb89f56dea'; //twilio Account SID
$serviceSid = 'IS4220abf29ae4169992b8db5fc2668b10'; //Notify service SID
$client = new Client($sid, $token);
$rs = $client->notify->services($serviceSid)->notifications->create([
    "toBinding" => [
        '{"binding_type":"sms", "address":"+919999999999"}',
        '{"binding_type":"sms", "address":"+919999999999"}'
    ],
    'body' => 'Test message 8',
    'statusCallback' => "your public end point to track sms delivery status"
]);
```